# ShowHeaderWhenEmpty, EmptyDataText, and EmptyDataTemplate not working in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

`Gridview` populates properly when data is returned, however `ShowHeaderWhenEmpty`, `EmptyDataText`, and `EmptyDataTemplate` all do not work, even when no records are returned.  I've read other solutions regarding CSSFriendly and some conflict where CSSFriendly disables the controls, however that doesn't seem to have solved the issue.

here is my `ASP gridview`

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" class="table table-striped table-hover" ID="gvPendingRequestsEP" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="submitted_by" HeaderText="submitted by" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="date_submitted" HeaderText="date submitted" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="card_number" HeaderText="Card Number" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="beginning_date" HeaderText="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="beginning_time" HeaderText="time" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="total_time" HeaderText="hours" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="in_place_rank" HeaderText="Time/ Pay" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="status_id" HeaderText="Status" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                edit
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href="EPRequest.aspx?id=<%#Eval("card_number") %>">edit</a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is my code-behind

```
protected void PopulateCardManagers(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TimeHubDBCS"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            SqlCommand cmdFillEP = new SqlCommand();
            cmdFillEP = new SqlCommand("spSelectPendingRequestsEP", conn);
            cmdFillEP.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmdFillEP.Parameters.Add("@UserId", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lblUserLoggedIn.Text;

            DataSet dsRequests = new DataSet();
            DataTable dtEPCards;

            dsRequests.Tables.Add("dtEPCards");
            dtEPCards = dsRequests.Tables[0];

            SqlDataAdapter daPendingRequestsEP = new SqlDataAdapter();
            daPendingRequestsEP.SelectCommand = cmdFillEP;

            conn.Open();

            try
            {
                daPendingRequestsEP.Fill(dtEPCards);

                gvPendingRequestsEP.DataSource = dtEPCards;
                gvPendingRequestsEP.DataBind();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                PopupTitle = "error populating EP Card Manager: ";
                message = ex.Message;
                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + message + ex.Message + "');", true);
            }

        }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure an exception is not occuring? Try doing a Response.Write in your exception block since it may suppress the displaying of the empty template.

Comment: When you set ShowHeaderWhenEmpty and nothing is displaying, even though your code binds your grid to the datasource, that can mean that your datasource is null. You can avoid this by purposely loading an empty data table into your grid

Comment: @CosmosBanda,  Looks like that was the issue.  I added an if/else block to test if the datatable was null and if so, bound a an empty datatable to the gridview.  I'll credit you with the answer if you want to add it in below, otherwise I'll just write and answer myself.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `ShowHeaderWhenEmpty` to work you must provide a not null datasource to the gridview control. Therefore, if your current code is providing null, one way to go around the problem is to create an empty `datatable` and bind it to your `gridview`